# Is it Legal to make an artificial kidney despite the patent?

Tags: inventor, invention, medicine, health, healthcare

In reference to the patent: [US7083653](https://www.google.com/patents/US7083653)

Does this mean that Charles Jennings is the only one able to make an artificial kidney? If one is to use a personal design is that legal?

Answer (score 1):

Patent protection is defined by claims, if your device is having all components of patented one then you will be infringing it. Now if patent is active in US then you cannot do said claimed activity in US.

i doubt that personal use comes under bolar provisions.

Even if you use personal design and not the drawing provided in patent and claims cover your personal design you will be infringing said patent claims.